# understanding functors and monoids

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative, monoids

I have been looking over this code for so long now and I still do not understand what it is trying to do.

1. what does Functor ((,) x) mean?
2. Similarly, what does Applicative ((,) x) mean
3. why does pure a = (mempty ,a), what is mempty?
4. what are the last two lines of code doing

```
instance Functor ((,) x) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> (x,a) -> (x,b)
  fmap f (x,a) = (x,f a)

instance Monoid x => Applicative ((,) x) where
  pure :: a -> (x,a)
  pure a = (mempty ,a)

  (<*>) :: (x,a -> b) -> (x, a) -> (x, b)
  (<*>) (x, f) (x',a) = (x <> x', f a)
```

Comment: The canonical form of `(x, y)` is `(,) x y`, so `(,) x` is a type of a tuple where the first type is filled in, and the second one will be obtained in the signature with type application.

Comment: I think however that it might be useful to first understand the concept of a `Functor` and `Applicative`, not care too much about some syntax peculiarities.

Comment: do you know what `instance` means?

Comment: I know instance is an object of a particular class

Comment: If I tell you that this code implements (a generalisation of) *operations that write logs*, would it help? Imagine a log as a string that each operation may add to. A string is a monoid with respect to concatenation. That's the monoid we see in the code. Try playing with it. Say, what `("add one;", (1 +)) <*> (("multiply by two;", (2 *)) <*> (pure 42))` should do?

Comment: So why are we applying f to a only, why not fmap f (x,a) =  ( f x, f a)

Comment: should return 85

Comment: 85 with logs collected so far

Comment: "add one; multiply by two;"

Comment: @henry _I know instance is an object of a particular class_. I think you are missing what a type class is. I'd start from that point

Comment: It sounds like you may be lacking knowledge of some basic features of Haskell that need to be understood before you can make sense of this code. I highly recommend taking a look at [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters). Particularly relevant for this question are chapter 11, and (before that), the "Typeclasses 101" section of Chapter 3. Depending on your familiarity with Haskell, you may find yourself needing information from earlier chapters to understand things - but rest assured that anything you are unsure about should be explained in the book somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be helpful to explicitly look at a special case of this instance:

```
instance Functor (String, ) where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> (String, a) -> (String, b)
  fmap f (x,a) = (x, f a)

instance Applicative (String, ) where
  pure :: a -> (String, a)
  pure a = ("", a)

  (<*>) :: (String, a -> b) -> (String, a) -> (String, b)
  (<*>) (x, f) (x',a) = (x++x', f a)
```

The *tuple section* `(String, )` [not actually legal syntax in Haskell type-level expressions] means this: a type constructor that takes any type `a` and puts it in the tuple together with the already fixed `String`. Check it out in value-level code:

```
Prelude> :set -XTupleSections 
Prelude> (1, ) "bla"
(1,"bla")
Prelude> map (, False) [2.3, pi]
[(2.3,False),(3.141592653589793,False)]
```

This is syntactic sugar for

```
Prelude> (\y -> (1,y)) "bla"
(1,"bla")
```

or

```
Prelude> ((,) 1) "bla"
(1,"bla")
```

and that form *is* valid also on the type level, i.e. `((,) String)` or `((,) x)` is the way you actually need to write it in the instance head. The point is, that is a *type level function* which maps types to the tuple-types where they're paired with a `String`. That type-level function is the functor.

Now, `String` with its *empty value* `""` and *concatenation* `++` is just a special case of a monoid:

```
instance Semigroup String where
  (<>) = (++)
instance Monoid String where
  mempty = ""
```

...and those are the only `String` operations/values we used in the `Functor`&`Applicative` instances, so you might as well replace `String` with a type variable `x` which merely needs to be constrained to be a monoid type.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: I am going to mention `Product` and `Min`. If you have not heard of them, those are simply two wrappers, which let us create monoids for `Int` and `Ord a => a` accordingly (the details are going to be shown later, but you might already guess from their names what kind of behaviour we want).**

1, 2.: `((,) x)` is a type for a tuple with its first component occupied by `x`. Therefore, its kind is `* -> *`. All `Functor` and `Applicative` instances have kinds `* -> *`, thus we may try to write those instances down for our case. They just so happen to be quite reasonable.

3, 4.:

Such instances help you build up a log, which is stored in the first component of the pair
(the value itself being stored in the second). As @leftaroundabout has shown, `String` works just fine for such tasks. Thinking in terms of building up logs, the explanation becomes fairly simple:

1. Defining the instance for `Semigroup` (that is defining `(<>)`) you decide how to merge your logs. For `String` it is `(++)`; for `Product` - `(*)`; for `Min` - `min` and so on.
2. Defining the instance for `Monoid` (that is defining `mempty`) you decide what should be in your log at the beginning of the computation. That is something that would not spoil the log. For `String` it is `""`; for `Product` - `1` as `1 * x = x = x * 1`; for `Min` - `minBound` as: `min minBound x = x = min x minBound` and so on.

That is why `pure x` creates an empty log (`mempty`) *around* `x`.

`(w, f) <*> (w', x) = (w <> w', f x)` merges two logs together (besides the application).

This structure is often called `Writer` for this reason.

P.S.: There is also a reasonable `instance Monoid w => Monad ((,) w)`:

```
instance Monoid w => Monad ((,) w) where
    (w, x) >>= k = let 
                      (w', x') = k x
                   in (w <> w', x')
```

Comment: *["around"](https://www.google.com/search?q=CLOS+around+methods)* `x`. :)